# newbie: how to save and print objects in Java?

Tags: java

Sorry for the newbie question, but I'm just starting with programming and this stuff is complex.

I have the following code excerpt that creates objects of the type Book to build my library.

```
 public class Library {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

   int bookID = 0;
   String title;
   String author;
   int printDate;


   Book book1 = new Book(bookID++, "Book title example", "Book author example", 1990);
   Book book2 = new Book(bookID++, "Another book title", "Another author", 1992);

   // Now lets print the available book titles in my library
   for (int i = 1; i <= bookID; i++)
     System.out.println(book[i].title);

 }
}
```

This is not working, of course, but I'm not sure how to address all the objects to print them at once.

It seems the solution would be to send all the Book objects info to some kind of array, and then print the array contents.

But if I want to add new books to the library, then I have to build a new array, and this doesn't seem like the best way to do it.

Also, whenever the program initializes, the bookID will always be at 0.
But if there is a way to force the bookID variable to always contain the last introduced bookID, then I wouldn't have to use the bookID++ operator when setting the ID for each book. It would just read from somewhere (maybe that array that contains object info?) and add one value to the new Object.

Sorry, this is probably easy stuff, but I just started learning a couple of weeks ago.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do so by adding Array, and store all books in that Array. As far as i can see there is no Array ( nor any other object where you store more than 1 data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems the solution would be to send all the Book objects info to some kind of array, and then print the array contents.

Right

> But if I want to add new books to the library, then I have to build a new array, and this doesn't seem like the best way to do it.

The `java.util` package already has a bunch of classes for dealing with lists, sets, and more, of objects. Check for subclasses of `java.util.Collection`.

> Also, whenever the program initializes, the bookID will always be at 0. But if there is a way to force the bookID variable to always contain the last introduced bookID, then I wouldn't have to use the bookID++ operator when setting the ID for each book. It would just read from somewhere (maybe that array that contains object info?) and add one value to the new Object.

You must store it somewhere. A file, a database, whatever. For starters try with a file. Of course, you will have to write/update the contents of a file yourself.